# SSL proxy not working when using inside of .exe [Python]

Tags: python, ssl, web-scraping, request, proxies

I have created an .exe file with the help of pyinstaller module, the problem resides when I perform a request to an endpoint via the .exe using https proxies which throws me an error:

```
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.lustmexico.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /products.json (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('_ssl.c:1059: The handshake operation timed out')))
```

But instead, when I execute the request via my main.py file (e.g. the main entry point of the program, using python files, not .exe converted yet) no error happens

Here's how my proxies are configured:

```
ip = "IP OF MY PROXY"

proxies = {
        "https": 'https://' + ip,
        "http": 'http://' + ip
    }
    return proxy
```

And the way I perform the request is:

```
r = requests.get(self.link + "/products.json", proxies=proxies, headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
```

At first instance I guessed was the timeout, but its to high now and I have tested and is not, for sure, the main error cause

After doing my long research I found that there was an error on my https proxies or SSL installed in my machine but not really sure about that, yet I don't understand the problem, please help

Comment: Does requesting the url with your proxy outside of your .exe works (With curl for example) ? And do you have the same error when requesting an http url ?

Comment: @Paul yes it works with the same url and no I don't have the same error when requesting an HTTP url